# Tomcat StandardRoot: Only Adds One Jar File

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm using Tomcat 8.0.27.0.  I extended the `org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot` class and reference it in my web application's `context.xml` file.

In my custom `StandardRoot` I want to add external Jars to the web application's classpath.  I've done this in the overridden `initInternal` method:

```
super.initInternal();

JarResourceSet jarResourceSet = new JarResourceSet(this, 
    "/WEB-INF/classes", 
    "/path/to/first.jar", 
    "/") ;
super.addJarResources(jarResourceSet);

jarResourceSet = new JarResourceSet(this, 
    "/WEB-INF/classes", 
    "/path/to/second.jar", 
    "/");
super.addJarResources(jarResourceSet);
```

Later, when the web application starts, I use `FastClasspathScanner` to search for classes implementing a particular interface.  Both `first.jar` and `second.jar` have a class implementing the interface, so I expect to find them.

The problem is that only the class found in `first.jar` is found.  If I switch the order of adding the `JarResourceSet` classes so that `second.jar` is added via `super.addJarResources` first, then the class in `second.jar` is found, but not the one in `first.jar`.

So, only the first jar added via `addJarResources` is successfully added to the classpath.

I've also tried using the `addPreResources` and `addClassResources` methods instead of `addJarResources` with no change in behavior.

I also tried the `createWebResourceSet` method like this:

```
super.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.PRE, "/WEB-INF/classes", "/path/to/first.jar", null, "/");
super.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.PRE, "/WEB-INF/classes", "/path/to/second.jar", null, "/");
```

With similar results.

Interestingly, if I use the `RESOURCE_JAR` type  like this:

```
super.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/WEB-INF/classes", "/path/to/first.jar", null, "/");
super.createWebResourceSet(ResourceSetType.RESOURCE_JAR, "/WEB-INF/classes", "/path/to/second.jar", null, "/");
```

Then I get an error like this from `FastClasspathScanner`:

```
io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.MatchProcessorException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: the.class.i.am.LookingFor
```

So it's like it found the class... but can't find it?

I need to be able to add any number of jars to the classpath.  How can I do that?  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: What's the use-case here? Tomcat can already provide this capability via configuration instead of complicated subclassing (and then debugging).

Comment: I want to see if I can configure the Tomcat classpath based on an externally read properties file or database, on a per-webapp basis.